# Why is it that if I swap the position of two conditions with an 'and' operator in between that the result is somehow different?

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement

So I'm doing an exercise called missing number and I don't understand why this statement causes a list index out of range error.

```
if nums[i] != nums[j] and nums[i] < len(nums):
```

But when I use this condition the code works:

```
if nums[i] < len(nums) and nums[i] != nums[j]:
```

Aren't these two lines of code functionally the exact same? I was thinking maybe it's an order of precedence issue but even after I wrapped the it in brackets there was still an out of range error.

Here is the full code below:

```
 def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    i, n = 0, len(nums)
    while i < n:
        j = nums[i]
        if nums[i] != nums[j] and nums[i] < n:
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    
    for i in range(n):
        if i != nums[i]:
            return i
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean operators in Python use [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) logic, which means that if the first condition of the `and` is falsey, the second condition will not be checked.  As a result, the order of the conditions is significant.

In your example, since `nums[i]` is part of both conditions, we can conclude that the `IndexError` is coming from `nums[j]`.  We can also conclude that, for your input data, whenever `nums[i] < n`, `j` is always in range.  However, that may not hold for all inputs, so you should fix your logic to only check the value of `nums[j]` if `j < len(nums)`.

Comment: Ahhh I see, the test case I was using was [6,4,0,1,2,5], so nums[0] was already out of range, causing the error. Thanks for the help!